# react DataGrid: append custom filter operator without erasing the other operators

Tags: reactjs, datagrid

I'm using **MaterialUI's DataGrid** for React and I have created a custom filter operator for one of the columns.
I was able to add it to the column as mentioned in the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/filtering/) and it's working fine, however, this removed the other default operators (contains, equal, etc...).
This is how I did it:

```
columns: GridColDef[] = [
    {
        field: 'myFieldName',
        headerName: 'Column name',
        filterOperators: [MyCustomOperator],// this is the custom operator I have created
    }
]
```

How to append my custom operator and keep other operators?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @DeepakBiswal, I had to add all the operators myself, and implement the logic behind each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with `...getGridStringOperators()` and it's adding new filter at the end of all existing filter. So for your case it will be something like below:

```
columns: GridColDef[] = [
     ...getGridStringOperators(),
     {
        field: 'myFieldName',
        headerName: 'Column name',
        filterOperators: [MyCustomOperator],// this is the custom operator I have created
     }
]
```

Comment: ah that's nice :)